# Strange output when parsing text file

Tags: perl

i am parsing a text file with this code:

```
  open(INFO,  "file.txt") or die("Could not create file.");       
  foreach my $line (<INFO>)  
  {
     print $line;
  }
  close(INFO);
```

This is how the text file looks like:

```
      aaaaaa bbbb
```

And here is how printing to console looks like:

```
      a a a a a a    b b b b
```

I am guessing this is some kind of encoding or something like this.
does any one knows what kind of encoding is this and how i convert it to a regular ascii text?

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: windows. someone at work gave me this file. i don't know from which operating system it came from.

Comment: @Vera Have you tried too open the file with a hex editor to look if it are  `ASCII` character?

Answer (score 0):

As others said in the comments, the file is probably encoded and your text editor is hiding it from you. opening it in hex editor is the best way to be sure what a file contains.

If you have an encoded file, you need to open the file with encoding:

```
open(INFO, "<:encoding(UTF-16)", "file.txt") or die("Could not create file.");
```

as I guess that your file is UTF-16 encoded. If you learn (using the hex editor) that your file have other encoding, switch the name.

Now, when it comes to printing, as long as it really contain only ascii, nothing special need to be done. if not, you need to tell perl that you are going to dump unicode to the stdout:

```
binmode STDOUT, ":encode(utf8)";
```

I recommend reading about encodings in general, the Encode module, open and binmode commands.